# What happens if an Azure Data Factory is triggered twice at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

On the same pipeline I have two triggers :

1- Scheduled : 3 times a day

2- BlobEvent : When a file is created on Blob Storage

So far I have no problems but I was wondering what if the two were triggered at the same time, what happens then ? Will one be put on hold until the first one ends or will they both be executed at the same time (This could be a problem, if so what would be your suggestion to stop that?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipelines have a concurrency limit at pipeline level which *can* help control this.  The default is blank (ie up to 50) so set it to 1 if you want to control concurrent executions.

[image: ADF concurrency]

However the current behaviour is for this to queue subsequent pipeline runs, not stop them altogether, so you may need to build some logic into your pipeline to determine 'have I already processed this file?' eg with a [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity)
or build something in the pipeline that moves the file after it's been successfully processed for example - it depends what you're doing.

Review the behaviour [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pipeline-trigger-troubleshoot-guide#pipeline-status-is-queued-or-stuck-for-a-long-time) and upvote on this feedback item [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41901892-concurrency-limit-should-avoid-queueing-new-runs).